# Inverse of a certain unit upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I don't know if there is a certain name for this matrix. but I want to show

$\begin{pmatrix}1&\gamma&\gamma^2& \ldots & \gamma^n\\
&1&\gamma&\ddots&\vdots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\gamma^2\\
&&&1&\gamma\\ 
&&&&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}1&-\gamma&& & \\
&1&-\gamma&&\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\\
&&&1&-\gamma\\ 
&&&&1\end{pmatrix}\,\in\mathbb{C}^{(n+1)\times (n+1)}$

Where the blank spaces of the matrices represent zero entries.

I am not sure how to give a concise proof for this. When I try to use the blockwise inversion or directly multiply these matrices together, I get bogged down in computations. Is any theorem or property I should consider for this proof?

Comment: Can you explain more about your direct multiplication?

Comment: @Rhcpy99 I would rewrite the right-hand matrix as a collection of column vectors, multiplying each to the left-hand matrix to get rows of what should be an identity matrix. Something like [this](http://allenchou.net/2014/02/game-math-alternate-views-on-matrix-multiplication/). The problem is keeping track of the vectors and knowing what they are doing. So when i=j, jth column of the right hand matrix will give a 1 when multiplied with the ith row on the left hand side, and will give a 0 when i=/=j. However, it is hard to explain why, especially without an explicit description of each vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find a nice formula for $M^{-1}$, where 
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}1&-\gamma&& & \\
&1&-\gamma&&\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\\
&&&1&-\gamma\\ 
&&&&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
In particular, it is useful to note that $M = I - N$, where
$$
N = \begin{pmatrix}0&\gamma&& & \\
&0&\gamma&&\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\\
&&&0&\gamma\\ 
&&&&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
from there, we could use the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) to compute
$$
M^{-1} = (I - N)^{-1} = I + N + N^2 + N^3 + \cdots
$$
where we note that $N^k = 0$ whenever $k \geq n+1$.  With that, you can conclude that
$$
M^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&\gamma&\gamma^2& \ldots & \gamma^n\\
&1&\gamma&\ddots&\vdots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\gamma^2\\
&&&1&\gamma\\ 
&&&&1}
$$
which is equivalent to the result you're looking for.

As for the name of this kind of matrix, I would say that it's an upper triangular [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).

---

A formal (inductive proof) for the formula of $N^k$: we wish to show that
$$
[N^k]_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
\gamma^k & j-i = k\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $[A]_{i,j}$ denotes the $i,j$ entry of $A$.  The base case (either $k=0$ or $k=1$) holds trivially.  For the inductive step: we note that if $i,j$ are between $1$ and $n+1$ 
$$
[N^{k+1}]_{i,j} = [N N^{k}]_{i,j} = \sum_{p=1}^{n+1} N_{ip}[N^k]_{pj}
$$
We note that $N_{ip}[N^k]_{pj}$ is only non-zero if $N_{ip} \neq 0$ **and** $[N^k]_{pj} \neq 0$.  By our definition of $N$, $N_{ip}$ will only be non-zero if $p = i+1$.  On the other hand: by our inductive hypothesis, $[N^k]_{pj}$ will only be non-zero if $p = j-k$.  These can only be simultaneously true if $i+1 = j-k$, which is to say that $j-i = k+1$.  Thus, we conclude that $[N^{k+1}]_{i,j} = 0$ whenever $j-i \neq k+1$.

Whenever $j - i = k+1$, we compute
$$
[N^{k+1}]_{i,j} = \sum_{p=1}^{n+1} N_{ip}[N^k]_{pj} = 
N_{i,(i+1)}[N^k]_{(j-k),j} = \gamma \cdot \gamma^k = \gamma^{k+1}
$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: How would I go about showing that each N^k has the desired form. For example, that N^2 has gamma squared in each of the needed entries?

Comment: @AndreuPayne I see now that you're particularly concerned with having a detailed, rigorous proof for the formula.  With that in mind, I've added a proof of the formula for $N^k$.  I hope this suffices.