# Simplifying a tough experession of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

In the Dirac's $bra$ and $ket$ notation,  $|x ~\rangle$ (pronounced as $ket~ x$ represents a column vector and $\langle y ~|$ (pronounced as $bra~y$) a row vector, such that $\langle x | y \rangle $ is the inner product.   Consider the following:

$F(i,k) = \langle i | \Big(\sum\limits_{x=-L}^L |x-1\rangle \langle x|\Big)^{L-k} \Big(\sum\limits_{y=-L}^L |y+1\rangle \langle y|\Big)^{k}|0 \rangle$

Here, $L \in \{ 0,1,2,3, \dots \}$,  $k \in \{ 0,1,2,3, \dots \}$, and  $i \in \{ 0,1,2,3, \dots \}$, and $k \le L$. Also,

$| -L \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\ \vdots \\ \end{pmatrix}_{2L+1,1} $, $\cdots$,  $| L \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} \vdots \\0\\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}_{2L+1,1} $

What is the general form of $F(i,k)$?

Comment: Are the kets $|k\rangle$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,\dots$ orthonormal?

Comment: Yes. In fact in my question, $\langle i | j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$, i.e., are orthogonal unless $i=j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helpful observation in simplifying this is that
$$
\Big(\sum\limits_{x=-L}^L |x-1\rangle \langle x|\Big)^{k} = 
\Big(\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-1} |x\rangle \langle x+1|\Big)^{k} = 
\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-k} |x\rangle \langle x+k|.
$$
We can similarly observe (or use the adjoint of the above) to find that
$$
\Big(\sum\limits_{y=-L}^L |y+1\rangle \langle y|\Big)^{k} = 
\sum\limits_{y=-L}^{L-k+1} |y+k\rangle \langle y|.
$$
With that established, it is straightforward to verify that
$$
F(i,k) = \langle i+L-k|k\rangle = \delta_{i+L,2k}.
$$

---

Proof of first equation: proceed by induction. We note that
$$
\begin{align}
\Big(\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-1} |x\rangle \langle x+1|\Big)^{k} &= 
\Big(\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-1} |x\rangle \langle x+1|\Big)\Big(\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-1} |x\rangle \langle x+1|\Big)^{k-1}
\\ & = \Big(\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-1} |x\rangle \langle x+1|\Big)\Big(\sum\limits_{y=-L-1}^{L-k+1} |y\rangle \langle y+k-1|\Big)^{k-1}
\\ & = 
\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-1}
\sum\limits_{y=-L-1}^{L-k+1}
|x\rangle \langle x+1|y\rangle \langle y+k-1|
\\ & = 
\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-1}
\sum\limits_{y=-L-1}^{L-k+1}
\delta_{x+1,y}
|x\rangle \langle y+k-1|
\\ & = 
\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-k}
|x\rangle \langle (x+1)+k-1|
= 
\sum\limits_{x=-L-1}^{L-k}
|x\rangle \langle x + k|.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Could you be little detailed, please?

Comment: How did you reach at $\Big( \sum\limits_{-L-1}^{L-1} | x \rangle \langle x+1 | \Big)^k = \sum\limits_{-L}^{L-k} |x \rangle \langle x +k|$?

Comment: @Rob It's equivalent to the proof [that I have written here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3206108/81360) (with $b = 1$).

Comment: could you be kind to prove the first equation in your answer?

Comment: @Rob See my latest edit

Comment: Thanks a lot!. One minor doubt. How did the upper limit iof $x$ change from $L-1$ to $L-k$? I was stuck at the same point!

Comment: @Rob Note that if $x > L-k$, then the corresponding $y = x+1$ would satisfy $y > L-k+1$. However, we never have $y > L - k + 1$ in the original sum.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a ton!!