# How to find the inverse matrix, where $a_{ij} = p^{|i-j|}$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find the inverse of the matrix $A = (a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij} = p^{|i-j|}$. Assuming the matrix is invertible.

What's the special thing of this matrix?

I can only know what this matrix is. But I don't know how to derive its inverse.

Comment: If $|p|<1$, then [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86316/81360) applies

Comment: It can be interesting to see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2708647/305862) where I give an interpretation with autoregressive processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matrix is known as a Kac-Murdock-Szego (KMS) matrix. Apparently, its inverse has the nice [formula described here](https://nhigham.com/2021/07/06/what-is-the-kac-murdock-szego-matrix/) whenever it is invertible (which occurs whenever $p \neq \pm 1$). In particular, we have
$$
A^{-1} = \frac 1{1 - p^2}\pmatrix{
1&-p&0&\cdots&0\\
-p & 1 + p^2 & -p & \ddots&\vdots\\
0&-p&1+p^2&\ddots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&-p\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & -p & 1+p^2}.
$$

Comment: Great. How to derive this inverse matrix?

Comment: If you want a proof, it's easy to compute the entries of the product $AA^{-1}$ and show that they correspond to the entries of the identity matrix

Comment: @Jonathen You multiply this matrix with the original and check it gives you the identity. Since cols and rows are almost all zero it is easy to compute the dot product.

Comment: @Jonathen If you really want a "derivation", then you might be content with applying [this formula for the inverse of the $L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2939921/81360) from the Cholesky decomposition of $A$ as given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86316/81360) that I linked earlier. This technically only applies in the case that $|p|<1$, but you could argue that any formula that applies for all $p$ with $|p|<1$ must apply more generally.