# Proof of positive definiteness of symmetric matrix from equation based on index

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

I am trying to prove that a matrix following a certain structure based on its index is always positive definite. Each entry in the matrix has the following value:

$$ \text{e}^{- \alpha \cdot |i-j|} ~~~~,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$$

Where $i$ and $j$ represent the indices of the rows and columns of the matrix. Thereby, a $N \times N$ matrix $M$ would look like the following:

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & \text{e}^{- \alpha} & \cdots & \text{e}^{- \alpha \cdot (N-1)} \\
\text{e}^{- \alpha} & 1 & \ldots & \text{e}^{- \alpha \cdot (N-2)} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots &\vdots\\
\text{e}^{- \alpha \cdot (N-1)} & \text{e}^{- \alpha \cdot (N-2)} & \ldots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have tried to prove that the quadratic form of the matrix is positive:

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^N\smallsetminus\{0\}\quad x^T M x > 0
$$

But I don't know how to prove that the following summation is always positive:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N x_i x_j \, \text{e}^{- \alpha \cdot |i-j|}
$$

I do realize that setting $\alpha=0$ results in $\left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right)^2$, but I assume that this is not proof enough.

If anyone could give a hint I would be very gratefull!

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86316/81360), taking $a = e^{-\alpha}$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're willing to use an existing formula for the [inverse of this matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540573/81360), then you can simply show that $M^{-1}$ is positive definite (since $M^{-1}$ is [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix)), and your conclusion follows.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I needed. Thank you!